# Maven and Vaadin to build war correct

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I trying to compile a web app for Tomcat7 using Vaadin and Maven and I have themes and widgetset.

​I'm using Eclipse.

files:

```
/src/maim/java/com/na7kr
​/src/webapp (do not know why?)
​/src/resources (do not know why?)
​/target and lots of follder it makes
​/WebContent/META-INF
/WebContent/VAADIN
/WebContent/WEB-INF
```

pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>YT-100_ATU_Controller</groupId>
    <artifactId>YT-100_ATU_Controller</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>YT-100_ATU_Controller</name>

   <!-- properties -->
    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>7.5.7</vaadin.version>
        <productionMode>false</productionMode>
        <vaadin.theme>themes01</vaadin.theme>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.1-SNAPSHOT</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.source.version>1.8</project.source.version>
        <project.target.version>1.8</project.target.version>
        <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
    </properties>
    <!-- end properties -->

    <!-- repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>oss-snapshots-repo</id>
            <name>Sonatype OSS Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!-- end repositories -->

    <!-- dependencyManagement -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-archetype-widget</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-archetype-application</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- end dependencyManagement -->

    <!-- dependenciest -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>loginform</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- dependenciest -->

    <!-- build -->
    <build>
        <!-- plugins -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                    <source>${project.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${project.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude some unnecessary files generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**, WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>clean</goal>
                          <goal>resources</goal>
                          <goal>update-theme</goal>
                          <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                          <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                          <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>WebContent/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- plugins -->

        <!-- pluginManagement -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <!-- TODO Remove when http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/14924 is resolved -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[7.5.7,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>clean</goal>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <!-- end pluginManagement -->
    </build>
    <!-- end build -->
</project>
```

I get:

```
​/META-INF
​/VAADIN/themes/themes01 ( with only one SCSS and no CSS or images)
​(/VAADIN/widgetsets is missing)
​/WEB-INF/classes/com/ etc
/WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetset (why?)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move the files around  /WebContent to /src/webapp and that made it work OK